# Amazon s3 URL + being encoded to %2?

Tags: amazon-s3

I've got Amazon s3 integrated with my hosting account at WP Engine. Everything works great except when it comes to files with + characters in them.

For example in the following case when a file is named: *test+2.pdf*
http://support.mcsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/test+2.pdf = does not work.

The following URL is the amazon URL. Notice the + charcter is encoded. Is there a way to prevent/change this? 
http://mcsolutionswpe.s3.amazonaws.com/mcsupport/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/test%2b2.pdf

Other URLs work fine:
Amazon -> http://mcsolutionswpe.s3.amazonaws.com/mcsupport/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/test2.pdf
Website -> http://support.mcsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/test2.pdf

Answer (score 6):

If I understand your question correctly, then no, there is no way to really change this.

The cause appears to be an unfortunate design decision made on S3 many years ago -- which, of course, cannot be fixed, now, because it would break too many other things -- which involves S3 using an incorrect variant of URL-escaping (which includes but is not quite limited to "percent-encoding") in the path part of the URL, where the object's key is sent.

In the query string (the optional part of a URL after `?` but before the fragment, if present, which begins with `#`), the `+` character is considered equivalent to `[SPACE]`, (ASCII Dec 32, Hex 0x20).

...but in the path of a URL, this is not supposed to be the case.

...but in S3's implementation, it is.

So `+` doesn't actually mean `+`, it means `[SPACE]`... and therefore, `+` can't also mean `+`... which means that a different expression is required to convey `+` -- and that value is `%2B`, the url-escaped value of `+` (ASCII Dec 43, Hex 0x2B).

When you upload your files, the `+` is converted by the code you're using (assuming it understands this quirk, as apparently it does) into the format S3 expects (`%2B`)... and so it must be requested using `%2B` so when you download the files.

Strangely, but not surprisingly, if you store the file in S3 with a space in the path, you can actually request it with a `+` or a space or even `%20` and all three of these should actually fetch the file... so if seeing the `+` in the path is what you want, you can sort of work around the issue by saving it with a space instead, though this workaround deserves to be described as a "hack" if ever a workaround did.  This tactic will not work with libraries that generate pre-signed `GET` URLs, unless they specifically are designed to ignore the standard behavior of S3 and do what you want, instead... but for public links, it should be essentially equivalent.