# Why can't I download from S3 using wget?

Tags: python-3.x, wget

When I put https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/fhv_tripdata_2015-01.csv into a browser, I can download a file no problem. But when I say,

```
wget.download('https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/fhv_tripdata_2015-01.csv', out='data/')
```

I get a 404 error. Is there something wrong with the format of that URL?

This is not a duplicate of [HTTP Error 404: Not Found when using wget to download a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44828446/http-error-404-not-found-when-using-wget-to-download-a-link). wget works fine with other files. This appears to be something specific to S3 which is explained below.

Comment: How do you know the issue is because of the url and not, let's say, the headers?

Comment: I wouldn't even know how to check that. What would I even be looking for?

Comment: You could just use the requests package. requests.get(url) should do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP Error 404: Not Found when using wget to download a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44828446/http-error-404-not-found-when-using-wget-to-download-a-link)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause is a bug in S3, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38285197/4323

One workaround is to use the `requests` library instead:

```
r = requests.get('https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/fhv_tripdata_2015-01.csv')
```

This works fine.  You can inspect `r.text` or write it to a file.  For the most efficient way, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39217788/4323